# How to extract multiple values from the same string and put them into a matrix in R

Tags: r, string, split

In one field of my table have a string that looks like this for several hundred samples:

*Blasts and mononuclear cells were purified from bone marrow or peripheral blood aspirates of acute myeloid patients. Samples contained 80-100 percent blast cells. Total RNA was extracted by lyses with guanidium isothiocyanate followed by cesium chloride gradient purification.* FAB=**M1**, Karyotype=**"t(8;21)"**, FLT3 ITD=**pos**, FLT3 TKD=**pos**, N-RAS=**neg**, K-RAS=**neg**, EVI1=**neg**, cEBPa=**neg**

The italicized text in the first couple of sentences is identical so I would like to remove that. In the last sentence, I would like to extract each of the bolded values associated with the different classifications and put them into separate fields of a matrix, where **M1** would be [1,1], **t(8;21)** would be [2,1], **pos** would be [3,1] and so on but I am not sure where to start with this, especially since some of the values are missing, for example (FAB=, Karyotype=, etc...), the values in the **Karyotype** field sometimes have quotations as in the example above, and other times it is numeric and may contain special characters, such as **-7**.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that SO is a Q&A site, not a code writing service. While someone is probably going to help you, you should at least provide some attempts and document your fruitless efforts. Also, the more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: If some values are missing, are the comma's still in place? Otherwise, try to give a slightly bigger example with some more of different and missing values. One field containing different things as -7, "t(8;21)", etc is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty direct method. Demonstrated on two copies of your input string.

```
input = 'Blasts and mononuclear cells were purified from bone marrow or peripheral blood aspirates of acute myeloid patients. Samples contained 80-100 percent blast cells. Total RNA was extracted by lyses with guanidium isothiocyanate followed by cesium chloride gradient purification. FAB=M1, Karyotype="t(8;21)", FLT3 ITD=pos, FLT3 TKD=pos, N-RAS=neg, K-RAS=neg, EVI1=neg, cEBPa=neg'
input = rep(input, 2)

#remove everything up through "purification. "
result = sub(pattern = ".*purification\\. ", replacement = "", x = input)
# split by commas:
result = strsplit(result, split = ", ")
# delete everything through "="
result = lapply(result, sub, pattern = ".*=", replacement = "")

do.call(rbind, result)
#      [,1] [,2]          [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8] 
# [1,] "M1" "\"t(8;21)\"" "pos" "pos" "neg" "neg" "neg" "neg"
# [2,] "M1" "\"t(8;21)\"" "pos" "pos" "neg" "neg" "neg" "neg"
```

Use `cbind` instead of `rbind` in the last step if you want the rows and columns switched. This should work just fine whether or not Karyotype has quotes. It will handle the missing data as long as it is on the value that is missing, something like `"FAB=, Karyotype..."`, filling in an empty string. You may want to replace empty strings with `NA` as an additional step.

Comment: This worked exactly as I had hoped. @Victor below, that also works. Thank you both for helping a physiologist accomplish programming tasks!

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is using regular expressions, for this example is:

```
string <- 'Blasts and mononuclear cells were purified from bone marrow or peripheral blood aspirates of acute myeloid patients. Samples contained 80-100 percent blast cells. Total RNA was extracted by lyses with guanidium isothiocyanate followed by cesium chloride gradient purification. FAB=M1, Karyotype="t(8;21)", FLT3 ITD=pos, FLT3 TKD=pos, N-RAS=neg, K-RAS=neg, EVI1=neg, cEBPa=neg'
```

1.- First you `split` the string by `,`

```
string <- strplit(string,',')[[1]]

## You will have a vector like this:

## [1] "Blasts and mononuclear cells were purified from bone marrow or peripheral blood aspirates of acute myeloid patients. Samples contained 80-100 percent blast cells. Total RNA was extracted by lyses with guanidium isothiocyanate followed by cesium chloride gradient purification. FAB=M1"
## [2] " Karyotype=\"t(8;21)\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
## [3] " FLT3 ITD=pos"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## [4] " FLT3 TKD=pos"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## [5] " N-RAS=neg"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
## [6] " K-RAS=neg"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
## [7] " EVI1=neg"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
## [8] " cEBPa=neg"
```

2.- Remove all the characters before the `=` with `gsub` and regular expressions:

```
gsub(".*=","",string)

## The result is a vector with "clean" data.

## [1] "M1" "\"t(8;21)\"" "pos" "pos" "neg" "neg" "neg" "neg"
```

The pattern `.*=` means that it will get all the character before the `=` and with `gsub` it will replace it with no character (`""`).

For more information about regular expressions in `R` use this [link](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html) it help me a lot.

Hope this can help.

Regards

Comment: This works well and the link on regular expressions is extremely helpful!